# Cookies set on response don't seem to persist

Tags: python, cookies, oauth, flask

I want to set some cookies while doing OAuth login.  However, the cookies don't seem to be there on the next request.  What is the right way to set cookies in the code below?

```
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    verifier = request.args.get("oauth_verifier","")
    if verifier:
        token = request.cookies.get("token")
        secret = request.cookies.get("secret")
        access_token = oauth_helper.get_access_token(token,secret,verifier)
        resp = make_response()
        resp.set_cookie("token_key", access_token.key, max_age= 7*60*60 * 1000)
        resp.set_cookie("secret_key", access_token.secret, max_age= 7*60*60 * 1000)
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        token, secret, registration_url = oauth_helper.get_request_token_url()
        resp = make_response()
        resp.set_cookie('token', token, max_age= 60 * 1000)
        resp.set_cookie("secret", secret, max_age= 60 * 1000)
        return redirect(registration_url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a response and setting some cookies, but then throwing that away and returning a different response with the redirect.  Instead, the redirect should be the response you set the cookies on.

```
resp = redirect('/')
resp.set_cookie('token_key', access_token.key)
resp.set_cookie('secret_key', access_token.secret)
return resp
```